# How do i call a method that requires an InterrupedException in a JButton ActionListner

Tags: java, jbutton, actionlistener, interrupted-exception

I want to be able to press a button and a small game using Java 2d is created. 
i have tried to use a try/catch but it gets stuck in an infinite loop (because of the while loop in the create method i guess)

```
  Button.addActionListener(new ActionListener ()  {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)  {

                        game.create();/***is a new window with a small 2d game,
                        the 'create' method requires and InterruptedException to be thrown.***/ 




                }

            });
```

here is the code from the create method:

```
public void create () throws InterruptedException {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Mini Tennis");
    GameMain gamemain = new GameMain();
    frame.add(gamemain);
    frame.setSize(350, 400);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    while (true) {
        gamemain.move();
        gamemain.repaint();
        Thread.sleep(10);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that your infinite loop is blocking the swing thread from responding to your button.

Try having your loop in a separate thread:

```
public void create () throws InterruptedException {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Mini Tennis");
    GameMain gamemain = new GameMain();
    frame.add(gamemain);
    frame.setSize(350, 400);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    (new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            gamemain.move();
            gamemain.repaint();
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
    }
    ).start();
}
```